# Как вывести все записи mysql_fetch_array, а не только одну как сейчас

Tags: php, mysql

Выводиться только первый результат, как сделать чтоб все выводились?      \

```
<?php
require 'scripts/connect.php';
$name = trim($_REQUEST['name']);
$facebook = trim($_REQUEST['facebook']);

$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' && facebook='$facebook'";
$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row)
{
    printf("<div class=\"resultat\"><table>
    <tbody><tr><th>Город:</th><th>Компания:</th><th>Телефон:</th><th>Категория:</th><th>Дата добавления:</th></tr>   

<tr>
<td>" .$row['name'] . "</td>
<td>" .$row['last_name'] ."</td>
<td>" .$row['email'] . "</td>
<td>" .$row['facebook'] . "</td>
<td>" .$row['time'] . "</td>
</tr>

    </tbody></table></div>"
    );
}
else{echo ("Найден специалист: 123<br/><br/>");}


?>
```

Comment: Вместо `if($row)` использовать `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`

Comment: **Внимание** Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL.

Comment: Какая версия PHP?
Есть два варианта, для более старых версии и для тех кто выше 5.6
Какой у тебя?

Comment: 5.6 если использую вместо if($row), while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) белая страница

Comment: @ВиталийНосиков, читайте руководство по PDO: http://phpfaq.ru/pdo

Comment: Спасибо, но уже нет смысла переделывать, придется работать с чем есть

Comment: вы уверены, что вашему условию `where` удовлетворяет несколько записей в действительности?

Comment: Если честно, то я просто пытаюсь сделать поиск по бд. Я не знаю как красивее и правильнее код написать(*

Comment: Т.е. вы только начали работать с базой, однако уже нет смысла переделывать? Логика?

Comment: **SQL Injection Alert!**,  **Outdated mysql_ extension usage warning!**

Comment: @Uranus Почему вы правите чужие ответы, а не даёте своего?

Comment: @0xdb, здесь ситуация не из заурядных. Вопрос поднят духом для улучшения, я просмотрел оба ответа, все они корректные, но требуют существенных улучшений. Я побоялся что третий ответ не достаточно хорошо улучшит вопрос в целом, нежели улучшение существующих. Сейчас, отправил автору ответа комментарий с предложением улучшить ответ.

Comment: "не достаточно хорошо улучшит вопрос в целом" - но хуже его точно не сделает. Уже данные ответы авторские и правки не должны их в корне менять, даже если они станут от этого только лучше. Если новый ответ предложит тоже решение, что и уже существующеее, но он будет более качественный, то его стоит дать. Даже если автор уже решил свою задачу и больше сюда не заходит, он только дал тему, которой пользуются другие. Вы же не новичок здесь и знаете как SO работает.

Answer (score 1):

Функция [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) является [итератором](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) - она предоставляет доступ к каждому элементу последовательности возвращаемой функцией [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php). Каждый вызов функции mysql_fetch_array сдвигает внутренний указатель вперед на одну позицию, и возвращает массив данных соответствующий текущей позиции, или **FALSE** если достигнут конец последовательности.

Для вывода всех элементов последовательности можно использовать оператор while, проверяя каждый раз не возвратила ли функция mysql_fetch_array значение **FALSE**.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  render_result($row);
}
```

> **Внимание** Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или
> [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php). Смотрите также инструкцию [MySQL: выбор API](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) и
> [соответствующий FAQ](http://php.net/manual/ru/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) для получения более подробной информации.
> Альтернативы для данной функции:
>
> [mysqli_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)
>
> [PDOStatement::fetch()](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Answer (score -1):

Скорее всего нужно сделать так:

```
require 'scripts/connect.php';
$name = trim($_REQUEST['name']);
$facebook = trim($_REQUEST['facebook']);
$sql_select = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = "'. $name . '" AND facebook = "' . $facebook . '"';
$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
$i = 0;
$users = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $users[$i]['name'] = $row['name']; 
    $users[$i]['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
    $users[$i]['email'] = $row['email'];
    $users[$i]['facebook'] = $row['facebook'];
    $users[$i]['time'] = $row['time'];
$i++;
}?>
<table>
<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
  <tr>
      <td><?= $user['name'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $user['last_name'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $user['email'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $user['facebook'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $user['time'] ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

P.S. Код не тестил, но надеюсь, что помог

Comment: Пустая страница(

Comment: Обновил код. Пробуйте :)

Comment: Неа, теперь ищет, но не отображает результаты)

Comment: Что значит "ищет"? Массив $users наполнился?

Comment: Нет, пустой результат

Answer (score -2):

Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL.

Я переделал бы так:

```
<?php
require 'scripts/connect.php';  //Надеюсь, здесь есть функция возвращающая $link
$link = connect_db();
$name = trim($_REQUEST['name']);
$facebook = trim($_REQUEST['facebook']);

$sql_select = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name`="' . $name . '" && `facebook`="' . $facebook . '"';
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql_select); // используем современный mysqli и добавляем в него $link

if (!empty($result)) {
die("Найден специалист: 123<br/><br/>"); // если запрос в базу ничего не нашел

}

//если есть результат запроса
foreach ($result as $res) : ?>

<div class="resultat">
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Город:</th>
        <th>Компания:</th>
        <th>Телефон:</th>
        <th>Категория:</th>
        <th>Дата добавления:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $res['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['last_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['facebook']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['time'];
            endforeach; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

скрипт scripts/connect.php переписать так:

```
<?php
function connect_db()
{
$host = 'localhost'; // сервер
$username = 'mysql'; //имя пользователя
$password = 'mysql'; //пароль
$dbname = '66'; //имя базы

//Создаем подключение
//параметры в скобках ("хост", "имя пользователя", "пароль")
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);
//Выбираем базу
//параметр в скобках ("имя базы, с которой соединяемся")
mysqli_select_db ($link,$dbname);

//Кодировки (ставьте UTF-8)
mysqli_query ($link,"set character_set_client='cp1251'");
mysqli_query ($link,"set character_set_results='cp1251'");
mysqli_query ($link,"set collation_connection='cp1251_general_ci'");

//Возвращаем соединение
return $link;
}
```

не забудьте проверить имя пользователя и пароль от mysql, потому в вашем примере какие то цифры, а по умолчанию так

Поправьте, если не прав.

Comment: К сожалению не ищет(

Comment: $link добавили? он есть вообще? что в $ result приходит? попробуйте сделать
    echo $sql_select; и выполнить выведеный результат в phpmyadmin.

Comment: Вот что в connect.php https://jsfiddle.net/peovtvrr/

Comment: и после подключения скрипта в добавь строчку $link = connect_db();

Comment: перепиши https://jsfiddle.net/tdLmfr4p/2/

Comment: Теперь пишет что нельзя соединиться с бд

Comment: Вот так работает все, но я не профи в php( https://jsfiddle.net/tdLmfr4p/3/

Comment: что работает это хорошо. для проверки создал у себя похожую базу и запустил скрипты. у меня все работает. скопируйте и посмотрите еще раз. проверьте имя пользователя и пароль от mysql

Comment: В конце надо добавить <?php>?. У меня просто связанный список городов и регионов и пишет ошибку

Comment: есть такая штука PSR называется. вот там написано что закрывающий тег ?> в файлах содержащих только PHP код ставить не нужно(connect.php), а во втором файле все закрыто. Дайте архив весь с проектом + дамп базы. посмотрю что не так.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52751/discussion-between---and-).

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/KYv1/bXZaYFNPg что касательно php переделал все. + немного html поправил. теперь разбирайся с js, там когда json приходит он его как undefined определяет. Но он точно приходит, потому что разные области разное количество городов отображают.